# How can I delete a selected row in a HTML table and also in MySQL by using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter. I have fetched data from MySQL and displayed it in a HTML table. **Now I need to delete selected rows in MySQL.**

For example, assuming there are 10 rows in the table and each row has an accompanying checkbox, and there is a **Delete** button above the table. If user selects the first five rows and clicks the Delete button, the five rows should be deleted in then MySQL Database. Then the HTML Table data will hide these rows automatically because of I have fetch Data from MYSQL Table.

How can this be done?

**HTML code :**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <button id="export" data-export="export">Export</button>
    <table id="export_table" class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">Created At</th>
          <th class="text-center">Title</th>
          <th class="text-center">Description</th>
          <th class="text-center">Prority</th>
          <th class="text-center">Status</th>
          <th class="text-center">Start Date</th>
          <th class="text-center">Due Date</th>
          <th class="text-center">End Date</th>
          <th class="text-center">By</th>
          <th class="text-center">Additional Info</th>
        </tr>
      <?php foreach ($a->result() as $task) { ?>      
        <tr class="active">
          <td><?php echo $task->time; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $task->title; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $task->description; ?></td> 
          <td><?php echo $task->priority; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $task->status; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $task->start_date; ?></td>  
          <td><?php echo $task->due_date; ?></td>    
          <td><?php echo $task->end_date; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $task->assigned_by; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $task->additional_info; ?></td> 
        </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Controller Code :**

```
public function user_profile() {
    $this->load->model('user_model');    
    $data['a']=$this->user_model->all();
    $this->load->view('user_profile', $data);
}
```

**Model Code :**

```
public function all() {
   $query = $this->db->get('issues');  
   return $query;
}
```

Comment: The clue is, you can add the checkbox first on your table, and then make sure you have an id for your table, cretae hidden input on each row and set the value with the the id, you need the javascript or jquery to check the checked status of the checkbox and if it is on that status and you can that value id you will send to the controller, the create inside controller a function to handle delete action, the ids you send will be the parameter receive the execute delete and dont forget to reditect into the table url

Comment: Do something like this $ids = array(4,5);
$this->db->where_in('id', $ids);
$this->db->delete('mytable');

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using the `delete` function of Codeigniter

You can pass the ids of the rows selected by the users to PHP via a form sumbit / ajax call.

And then delete the coressponding rows using the `delete` function.

**Note:** Make sure to add a where clause before the delete statement to delete particular rows.

**Example Code**

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->delete('issues');
```

Comment: @TamilselvanS glad that I could be of help. You can now mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Bro could you please give your gmail id for clarify my doubts if any...